# c++ generate thread safe random numbers

Tags: c++, multithreading, random, thread-safety

I've read some similar questions to the one I'm asking but the answers don't seem complete or completely clear to me.

I'm trying to parallelize a parameter scan that requires the repeated generation of a set of random numbers. With only one thread I currently do something like this:

```
int main() {
  //Get random number generators
  typedef std::mt19937 MyRNG;
  std::random_device rd;

  //seed generator
  MyRNG rng;
  rng.seed(rd());

  //make my uniform distributions for each parameter
  std::uniform_real_distribution<> param1(-1,1);
  std::uniform_real_distribution<> param2(-1,1);

  double x,y;
  //Do my scan
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    x = param1(rng)
    y = param2(rng)

   //Do things with x and y*
  }
```

In this way I get a new x and y for every scan. Now I want to utilize multiple cores to do this in parallel. So I turn define a function `void scan()` which essentially has the same contents as my main function. I then create multiple threads and each have them run `scan()`. But I'm not sure if this is thread safe using std::thread. Will my random number generation in each thread as it currently is be independent? Can I save myself time by creating my RNGs outside of my `void` function? Thanks.

Comment: Since you haven't shown your `scan()` function, we can't comment on it. But as long as each thread owns it's own exclusive `MyRNG` and distribution then there is no reason to worry about them being shared between threads.

Comment: ```Scan()``` will be identical to main().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably generate the *seeds* in `main`, and pass a seed to each thread function. I wouldn't use the output of `std::random_device` directly either--I'd put numbers into something like an `std::set` or `std::unordered_set` until I got as many seeds as I wanted, to assure that I didn't give two threads the same seed (which would obviously be a waste of time).

Something along this general line:

```
int do_work(unsigned long long seed) {

  //Get random number generators
  typedef std::mt19937 MyRNG;

  //seed generator
  MyRNG rng(seed);

  //make my uniform distributions for each parameter
  std::uniform_real_distribution<> param1(-1,1);
  std::uniform_real_distribution<> param2(-1,1);

  double x,y;
  //Do my scan
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    x = param1(rng);
    y = param2(rng);

   //Do things with x and y*
  }
}

static const int num_threads = 4;

int main() {
    std::set<unsigned long long> seeds;

    while (seeds.size() < num_threads)
       seeds.insert(std::random_device()());

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

   for (auto const seed: seeds)
       threads.emplace_back(std::thread(do_work, seed));

    for (auto &t : threads)
        t.join();
}
```

As an aside, using a single result from `random_device` to seed an `std::mt19937` restricts the generator quite a bit--you're giving it only 32 (or possibly 64) bits of seed, but it actually has 19937 bits of seed material. `std::seed_seq` attempts to ameliorate this to at least some degree (among other things, you can use a number of outputs from `std::random_device` to create the seed.

Oh, and given that your two instances of `uniform_real_distribution` use the same parameters, there's probably not a whole lot of need for two separate distribution objects either.